# Speed up Foreach on Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I have the following code. The dictionary "_ItemsDict" contains millions of records. this code takes so much of time to add items to associatedItemslst LIST. Is there a way to speed up this process.

```
foreach (var obj in lst)
{
    foreach (var item in _ItemsDict.Where(ikey => ikey.Key.StartsWith(obj))
                                   .Select(ikey => ikey.Value))
    {

        aI = new AssociatedItem
        {
            associatedItemCode = artikel.ItemCode
        };
        associatedItemslst.Add(aI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, by not putting millions of records in it or using a different data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide by a factor 5 or 6 the time by using Parallel.Foreach()

```
String obj = "42";
Parallel.ForEach(_ItemsDict, new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount},
            (i) =>
        {
            if (i.Key.StartsWith(obj))
                bag.Add(new AssociatedItem() { associatedItemCode = i.Value });
        });
```

But it seems there's definitely an architectural issue. [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is one way to go. Or you can use a

```
Dictionary<String,List<TValue>>
```

where you store all occurrence of each part of each String, and then reference associated objects.

Last but not least, if your data comes from a database, SQL server is very efficient at searching part of varchar with a clause as :

```
WHERE ValueColumn like '42%' (equivalent of StartsWith("42") )
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you may want to implement a [Trie/Radix Tree/Prefix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Quoted from wikipedia:

> A common application of a trie is storing a predictive text or autocomplete dictionary, such as found on a mobile telephone.
>
> (snip)
>
> Tries are also well suited for implementing approximate matching algorithms,[6] including those used in spell checking and hyphenation[2] software.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think using dictionary is helping you to make this code fater, the reason is dictionary are good for matching the complete key not the partial key , in your case it actually going through each key in the dictionary and finding the result. I would suggest you to use some other data structure to get the result faster , one of them s [TRIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. I have posted a blog here for auto complete using TRIE https://devesh4blog.wordpress.com/2013/11/16/real-time-auto-complete-using-trie-in-c/